# Rails 4 showing meta info

Tags: ruby-on-rails

By mistake, I ran into something of interest. To be short, this is the code I have a question about:

```
<h1>Listing available grids: </h1>
<table>
    <%= @grids.each do |grid| %> --> put in additional '=' by mistake
    <tr>
        <td>Grid number: <%= grid.id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', grid %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

This is what it outputs a line before the table:

```
[#<Grid id: 1, ***bunch of grid attributes***, 
created_at: "2015-08-13 08:29:07", updated_at: "2015-08-13 08:29:07">
```

And so on for every other grid that is made, I know that it's because of the **%=** instead of just **%** before the `@grids.each`, but I'd like to have some additional info on why exactly all of the info is being passed into a text line. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@grids` is a `Array` instance. When you will call `Array#each`, it return the array object `@grids` in your case while all iteration is completed. That's why you are getting all the data in a single line.

Comment: Pretty simple thing, but I didn't even know what to search for to find an answer to this. Thanks !